# AesManaged determine if password is wrong

Tags: c#, cryptography, aes

I've been working with the AesManaged class to encrypt some data and I have everything working properly when the correct password is provided.  However, if the wrong password is supplied for decrypt, even if it's the same length, I get the error "Padding is invalid and cannot be removed".

My question is: If I supply the wrong password, will I always get this message?  If not, is there a way to tell if the data was decrypted properly without knowing what the original data was?

Comment: Implementations that have returned to the user whether or not the padding was correct have led to serious cryptographic issues. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_oracle_attack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I supply the wrong password, will I always get this message?

No, 1 in 256 keys will result in garbage with valid PKCS#7 padding.  (Really 1/2^8 + 1/2^16 + 1/2^24 + ... + 1/2^128).  So the exception always means "the key is wrong" (assuming you somehow know everything else to be right), but not all "the key is wrong" produce the exception.

> If not, is there a way to tell if the data was decrypted properly without knowing what the original data was?

If you don't consider there to be an attack vector of a chosen ciphertext padding oracle then you can solve this with an in-the-message prefix.  The odds of a 4 byte prefix aligning AND a 1+ byte padding aligning start at 1/2^40.

Or you can (as zaph pointed out) MAC the encrypted message using a different key derived from the same password.  If the MAC works out then the contents are not tampered with, and the password is correct.

Protecting the message via a MAC is the better option, though it's slightly more complex.

Comment: Part of the problem with a prefix when there **is** an attack is the encryption must be done prior to the check, this violates the [Cryptographic Doom Principle](https://moxie.org/blog/the-cryptographic-doom-principle/) of running the least amount of code prior to authentication. IMO it is always better to do the most secure thing.

Comment: Yep, that’s why I said the MAC is better, and that in-message was only an option if there was believed to be no attack vector.

Comment: Thanks for this info.  In looking through the Microsoft references I found the [HMACSHA512()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha512?view=netframework-4.7) class that has some nice examples.  However, the next question this leads me to is how to store the "secret key".  Since the data is encrypted before going through the HMAC function is it safe to store the key with the HMAC in the file?

Comment: Yes it is safe to save the HMAC key, it does not need to be secret, just prefix it to the encryption. See RNCryptor-Spec (link in my answer) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Bad padding error messages generally mean that the decryption failed, it is a really poor error message. The padding is bad because the decryption failed and as a result the padding which is encrypted is incorrect. But as bartonjs points out the encreyption can fail with no padding error (by chnace).

If you need to detect incorrect decryption you need to add authentication, this generally means an HMAC of the encrypted data. Then prior to decryption the HMAC is  run over the encrypted data and compared.

For an implementation example see [RNCryptor-Spec](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor-Spec/blob/master/RNCryptor-Spec-v3.md).